# Scrollbars not showing up in JScrollPane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I know that there are similar topics about this problem, but I tried all the things I have found around. Nothing works. Scrollbars are still not showing up. This is the site I'm working on: http://www.dimitrinube.com/work/francescovanstraten/.

Scrollbars should appear when going on section like "stills", "food", etc. and scroll the images down.

This is the CSS: http://www.dimitrinube.com/work/francescovanstraten/css/base.css

Comment: I checked this in Firefox and I can see a scrollbar on right side.

Comment: yes in firefox works. doesn't in chrome and - for me - in safari.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's [a known issue](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/known_issues.html) on the site:

> In Webkit browsers, CSS must be included before JavaScript

I only get the issue in Chrome. Since your widths are done dynamically on the element that would break it. Move your

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
```

after you add the heights and widths.